# Is it even possible to record from a device and play the recording on another device simultaneously?

Tags: android, audio, bluetooth, android-audiomanager

Currently using AudioTrack and AudioRecord to record and play simultaneously, it's working great **on the same device** (either headset mic + headset speakers or phone mic + phone speakers). However, what I'd like to do is **record from a device and play from another**, for instance recording from my bluetooth headset microphone and then having the output on the device built-in speakers (or another pair of headset/headphones).

I have been trying for a few days but I could not find anything. Hence I am asking, is it even possible?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.